# How can I tell if an ad/employer is looking for full-time or contract positions?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I see search results, some have a salary listed so they're obviously looking for permanent staff, but the rest of the ads don't state what type of help they are looking for: contract and/or permanent.

I see some interesting roles but I don't want to blindly "apply" if they're only looking for permanent people because I'm only interested in contract positions. I don't want to waste their time or mine, perhaps I'm overly cautious/tentative about such things, as well as discerning about who I want to contact, but I suspect many developers feel the same way... we don't prefer the "throw lots of **** and see what sticks" technique in our approach.

There is an option in match preferences for permanent/contract, but not in search, and as far as I can tell the match preferences don't filter search results. The job listings don't indicate the employers preferences either. So how can I tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can currently filter by Permanent/Contract jobs:

[image]

We don't actually display this data on the job description itself (which is odd - seems like an oversight). We have some upcoming experiments where we'll be testing out different designs/data to show on the job detail, so hopefully we can add this.

Comment: This is good - but I can currently filter for 'contract' and get zero results, but without that filter I can see jobs that have 'contract' mentioned in the title or description. So I guess employers are not selecting/checking 'contract' as the employment type. LinkedIn suffers the same problem, the default is permanent and they're not forced to explicitly set it, so contract roles get advertised as perm (making it a useless filter/field). So perhaps the solution lies in forcing selection of contract, perm, or either, when placing ads (i.e. leaving the default is invalid input)?

Comment: @jhabbott Yes, you're right - if the data is bad then the filter becomes meaningless. I'll submit this problem and your suggestion to the team that handles this. Thanks for the note!